# Render PrimeFaces MegaMenu in JSF ui:composition

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following snippet of JSF code which consists of ui:composition tag using a custom component which works just fine - the file which has all this information is called header.xhtml.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:projsfhtml5="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/projsfhtml5">
    <ui:composition>
       <!-- Include Prime Faces mega menu here -->  
       <projsfhtml5:navbar label="Mega App"
       value="#{request.contextPath}/protected/pages/bookSearch.xhtml">
   <projsfhtml5:navitem label="Contact Us"
        value="#{request.contextPath}/public/pages/contactUs.xhtml" />
    <projsfhtml5:navitem label="About"
        value="#{request.contextPath}/public/pages/about.xhtml" />
    </projsfhtml5:navbar>

    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>
    <ui:insert name="headerText">Welcome to the online library</ui:insert>
    </h1>
    </div>
     </ui:composition>
 </html>
```

This file in turn is part of a simple.xhtml template, which is used as a template for many pages in the site.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

  <h:head>
 <title><ui:insert name="title">Welcome</ui:insert></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
     <ui:include src="common/bootstrapCSS.xhtml" />   
   </h:head>

   <h:body>
  <div class="container">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <ui:include src="common/header.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="footer"></ui:insert>
</div>

<ui:include src="common/bootstrapJS.xhtml" />
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

What I would like to end up doing is instead of the projsfhtml5:navitem tags in header.xhtml I would like to render the prime faces mega menu elements so as to use it to display menu items - this appears to work ( i.e the rendering part) but the menus don't expand correctly and there is no way to click any of the options. Has anyone tried this or has experience with it ?

Thanks

Comment: I resolved my own issue - I will be removing this question.